# Jetty 8 & ActiveMQ Classic - suppress Jetty version in HTTP response

Tags: security, jetty, activemq-classic

I'm currently facing the issue that we are using ActiveMQ Classic in version 5.11.3 with an integrated Jetty web server (V8.1.16v20140903) for management of the queues.
Even though we have right now 2023 there are different reasons why we can not upgrade ActiveMQ+Jetty.

Due to security reasons I'd like to suppress the version of Jetty in the HTTP-Response.

Based on the [API-Doc](https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.16.v20140903/apidocs/) (org.eclipse.jetty.server -> Class Server) their exists a method named `setSendServerVersion(boolean)` where the release of the version during a HTTP-Call can be controlled.

The original `jetty.xml` looks like that:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="securityLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <property name="name" value="ActiveMQRealm" />
        <property name="config" value="${activemq.conf}/jetty-realm.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="user,admin" />
        <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="admin" />
         <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint" />
        <property name="pathSpec" value="/api/*,/admin/*,*.jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="adminSecurityConstraint" />
        <property name="pathSpec" value="*.action" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="loginService" ref="securityLoginService" />
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>
                <ref bean="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" />
                <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler">
            <bean id="sec" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <property name="handlers">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />
                            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
                            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                        <!-- Enable embedded file server for Blob messages -->
                        <!--
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <property name="contextPath" value="/fileserver" />
                            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/fileserver" />
                            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                            <property name="parentLoaderPriority" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                        -->
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                            <property name="contextPath" value="/api" />
                            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/api" />
                            <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                            <property name="directoriesListed" value="false" />
                            <property name="welcomeFiles">
                                <list>
                                    <value>index.html</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                            <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean id="defaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
                            <property name="serveIcon" value="false" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
    </bean>

    <bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
             <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="Server" depends-on="jettyPort" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start"
        destroy-method="stop">

        <property name="connectors">
            <list>
                <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                     <!-- see the jettyPort bean -->
                    <property name="host" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.host']}" />
                    <property name="port" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.port']}" />
                </bean>
                <!--
                    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
                -->
                <!--
                <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
                    <property name="port" value="8162" />
                    <property name="keystore" value="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
                    <property name="password" value="password" />
                </bean>
                -->
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="handler">
            <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <property name="handlers">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="contexts" />
                        <ref bean="securityHandler" />
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

I've already tried to add this method using a `bean-xml` tag - and create a reference into the Server part, but sadly the broker won't start anymore.

I've tried also to add the property `sendServerVersion` with the value `false` in the `bean id="Server"`, but same result - the broker won't start anymore.

For the Jetty 9 there exists the class `HttpConfiguration` and a lot of examples how to suppress the release of the version. However, for version 8 I tried my best but failed.

Comment: Try adding the parameter to the Server bean:

'<property name="sendServerVersion" value="false" />'

Comment: Note: Jetty 9 is at End of Community Support, and Jetty 8 is at End of Life.

Comment: Note: most discovery tooling can identify a Jetty 7 or Jetty 8 server based on behavior, the Server response header being enabled or not will make no difference for a security audit.

Comment: Hi @MattPavlovich,
that was the first thing I've tried...sadly enough the jetty server won't start afterwards....

Comment: OK - I don't know why, but know it works....
Adding the property works and ActiveMQ is booting....
Thanks for your help.